# GTM rename dataLayer not working

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm using the following documentation to rename my dataLayer: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming

My code looks like this:

```
fsData = [{ 'pageName' : 'test' }]

<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NV9MP5D" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript><script>
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){
  w[l]=w[l]||[];
  w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
  var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';
  j.async=true;
  j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','fsData','GTM-NV9MP5D');
</script>
```

I then go to GTM and add a new dataLayer variable and configure it to contain the value of "pageInfo". I create a simple tag that prints out this variable and as a trigger I choose the default "All Pages" which is configured to fire as soon as GTM receives the gtm.js event from the above code snippet.

The issue is that my tag never fires and when I use the debugger I notice that my fsData object contains my data, the gtm.js event but the GTM debugger is showing that GTM is pushing all of it's objects and events to "dataLayer", not "fsData".

I now have:

```
window.dataLayer
0: {event: "gtm.dom", gtm.uniqueEventId: 0}
1: {event: "gtm.load", gtm.uniqueEventId: 4}

window.fsData
0: {pageInfo: test}
1: {gtm.start: 1524823378118, event: "gtm.js"}
```

So I suspect that GTM still expects me to use the name "dataLayer" but I don't understand why, because I followed the steps from the documentation.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An encoding problem in your snippet, expanding the ampersand before the `l` parameter: `&amp;l=` will cause it to drop the rename parameter to the gtm script that is being loaded. This puts everything after the gtm script takes over in the default dataLayer, leaving only the already pushed data in the lines of the snippet itself in the renamed layer.